# Miniprofiler apperas in IE 9 but not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I am running my MVC application locally using IIS express and Miniprofiler is working/appearing as it should in IE 9, but when I open the site in Chrome and Firefox I do not see the miniprofiler on any pages.

Miniprofiler is rendered in my shared layout file just before the ending  tag.

Why would miniprofiler appear in IE9 but not in Chrome or Firefox?